# append as html in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to append the value as html in angular

```
<div class="storycontent" ng-class="{show: show}">
       <a href="#/profile?{{review.id}}">{{review.name}}</a>: {{review.story}}
</div>
```

Here in the `{{review.story}}` I will have value like `<b>hello</b><i>something</i>` etc

The problem is its displaying the content as `<b>hello</b><i>something</i>` instead of **hello***something* (ie the styling is not applied)
I have to use jQuery to do this

```
$(".content").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).text())
});
```

How can i directly append as `.html()` instead of `.text()` in angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need Jquery for that. `ng-bind-html` can do the trick by himself.

```
<div class="storycontent" ng-class="{show: show}">
  <a href="#/profile?{{review.id}}">{{review.name}}</a>: 
    <span ng-bind-html="review.story"></span>
</div>
```

Moreover, it's also better to add this on your controller when you get the value. Because without this, `ng-bind-hmtl` isn't safe.

```
$scope.review.story = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.review.story);
```

**Note :** `$sce` have to be injected in your controller. It's not available directly with angularJS.

```
.controller('ControllerName', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {...
```

Comment: thanks for the extra tip
any idea why i am getting "$sce is not defined"

Comment: @vignesh It's a service, you have to inject it. Something like this `['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce)...` in your controller

Comment: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html
Working on this issue now i am getting <b>bold</b> in the result

Comment: @vignesh Your value isn't a string ? Anyway this isn't really matching with the initial question. Add a second one will be better I think.

Comment: yeah i have accepted the answer
checking for existing question on the same line

Comment: yes its an array. It will contain all the stories. I am having a ng-repeat to fetch from array

Comment: @vignesh Do an other with the second problem I'll look at it if you want. Here in comment, it's more like "pollution" and hard to say without the interesting par of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86968/discussion-between-vignesh-and-pierre-alexandre-moller).

Answer (score 2):

You can use directive ngBindHtml, more info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Also you have to remeber that before binding html you have to ensure Angular that it is safe. You can use ngSanitize for it and $sce.trustAsHtml function:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-bind-html="expression"`
expression is your html here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-bind-html` in angular.

By Docs: **ng-bind-html**

> Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the
>   element in a secure way. By default, the resulting HTML content will
>   be sanitized using the $sanitize service. To utilize this
>   functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by
>   including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core
>   Angular). In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies,
>   you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application.

Use: `ng-bind-html="review.story">`

Refer [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)